# How do I determine compatible version for google services plugin, gradle plugin and dart pub packages

Tags: android, gradle, dart, flutter, version

I'm learning flutter.  The "[Adding Firebase to Flutter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)" tutorial shows to use this; "com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1" but the latest version seems to be [4.2.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Also, I'd like to use suitable (latest?) version of packages from https://pub.dartlang.org/packages

Such as (currently): 
firebase_core 0.3.1+1 and 
google_sign_in 4.0.1+1

If I just choose the latest numbers I get a lot of compilation errors.

**My Questions is: where can I find the latest supports/compatible version numbers for these various components?**

The only thing I have found to work is to use:"com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1"  and to just keep downgrading pub package versions numbers until the compiler errors go away.  I feel like there must be a more sane way to deduce the correct version numbers to use for various components.

Anybody have any insight into this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I need to see error messages but it's probably about AndroidX. If you have to check the changelog files of your plugins (by the way it's a good practice since sometimes readme's are not updated), you will probably see

> **Breaking change**. Migrate from the deprecated original Android Support Library to AndroidX. This shouldn't result in any functional changes, but it requires any Android apps using this plugin to also migrate if they're using the original support library.

[google_sign_in 4.0.0 changelog](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in#400)

You can [avoid AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx) by using these packages listed or you can [migrate to AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx) with these instructions.

`flutter create` is not coming with androidx, it comes with android support libraries, but if you have Android Studio, it's easy to migrate it. In my case, I've migrated it.

Comment: Thanks for this.   I am trying to understand the advice.  I used android studio and ran "Refactor->Migrate to AndroidX"  I just get a message saying "No usages found in this project".  I'll add specific error messages and config file in the question above.

Comment: Please mark my answer as solved to close this issue, if my answer works for you.