# App Crash when Launch after adding flutter firebase_admob

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i just add new dependencies to `pubspec.yaml`, it's `firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+3` but after adding it i got app crash at launch.

here're my other dependencies, any idea to solve ?

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+1
  rxdart: ^0.20.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.2.0
  geolocator: '^3.0.0'
  localstorage: ^1.2.0
  crypto: ^2.0.6
  dio: ^2.0.0
  pigment: ^1.0.3
  validate: ^1.6.0
  hijri: ^0.2.5
  device_id: ^0.1.3
  vibrate: ^0.0.4
  date_format: ^1.0.5
  cron: ^0.2.1
  audioplayers: ^0.9.0
  google_fonts_arabic: ^1.1.7
  unicode: ^0.1.0
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
  flutter_compass: ^0.1.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.1+1
  http: ^0.11.3+16
  easy_alert: ^0.0.2
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.2.0
  app_settings: ^1.0.5
  flutter_local_notifications: ^0.5.0
  cached_network_image: ^0.6.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+3
  flutter_facebook_login: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login
      ref: e69fef3
  firebase_auth: ^0.8.2
  esys_flutter_share: ^0.0.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: Update ADMOB APPLICATION_ID meta-data in AndroidManifest.xml https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55706048/my-app-crashes-because-firebase-admob-dependency-flutter/56129903#56129903

Comment: i ran into same issue but after changing firebase_admob version to 0.5.2 or 0.5.5, this problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to see error messages but probably it’s about Android X. Reduce the package version or migrate your project to android x.

[Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55133911/9779791)

[Change log:](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob#080) 
[image: screenshot from changelog]