# my app crashes because firebase admob dependency flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am following the instructions from here: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_admob#-readme-tab- but the thing is that whenever I add and only add line firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+3 then it crashes. It just blinks open and dies.

```
 environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  cloud_firestore: ^0.9.13+1
  dependencies: ^0.1.5 # this was test if app crash on dependencies and seems not.
  #firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+3
  #admob_flutter: ^0.1.2
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # firebase_core: ^0.2.5  # add dependency for Firebase Core
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
```

Does someone have the same problem or can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added the `meta-data` tag under `activity` tag and couldn't figure out. So for those who may have done this silly mistake as me, please follow:

The `meta-data` tag for adding application Id needs to be added in the `AndroidManifest.xml` located at `\android\app\src\main` under the `application` tag and not under the `activity` tag like `meta-data` tags for NormalTheme or SplashScreenDrawable are mentioned under `activity` tag.

### For Example:

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.appname">
   <application android:label="[Your AppName]" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="[Your APP_ID]" />
          <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" .......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading the dependency version to firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+1

Comment: Hello, it did not change the end result.

Answer (score 0):

After adding firebase_core: ^0.3.0 to dependencies, it started working.

Comment: hi chazefate, pls. try if you can have Real ad. displayed using your own app id and ad unit id, many people including me can't get real ad shown, only test ad can be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Update ADMOB APPLICATION_ID meta-data in  AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" android:label="firebase_admob_example" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleTop"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection"
              android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_admob/example/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error and I fixed it ))).
You must paste meta data tag under application tag not activity.

Comment: That's the same explanation already given in the answer by The mentalist Coder.